# Use of temp table in joining for performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Is there any basic difference in terms of performance and output between this below two query?

```
select * from table1 
left outer join table2 on table1.col=table2.col
  and table2.col1='shhjs'
```

and

```
select * into #temp from table2 where table2.col1='shhjs'

select * from table1 left outer join #temp on table1.col=#temp.col
```

Here table2 have huge number of records while #temp have less amount.

Comment: Usually, single statement queries always gives best performance over the multi statement queries. As long as index seek can be attained within the execution plan of first query will be the best.

Comment: This is not true.  Sometimes the single-statement query becomes too complex to optimize effectively, or the effect of incorrect cardinality estimates causes later parts of the query to run much slower.

Comment: If you opt to go for your 2nd route, change your 1st command to `SELECT DISTINCT col INTO #temp FROM table2 WHERE table2.col1='shhjs'` For both routes, change the * in `SELECT * FROM table1` to just the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I used #temp (which have less data than table2) for joining. Does not that help the query to perform better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.  The second method is going to materialize a table in the temp data bases, which requires additional overhead.

The first method does not require such overhead.  And, it can be better optimized.  For instance, if an index existed on `table2(col, col1)`, the first version might take advantage of it.  The second would not.

However, you can always try the two queries on your system with your data and determine if one noticeably outperforms the other.